# .Net Core React + Web Api form post data always null

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post some form data to a .Net Core Web Api with React using fetch. I am able to hit the breakpoint inside the controller action, but the post data is always null. Any ideas why?

**Register.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Register extends Component {
static displayName = Register.name;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userName: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("UserName", this.state.userName);
    formData.append("Password", this.state.password);
    formData.append("ConfirmPassword", this.state.confirmPassword);
    
    fetch("api/account/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label for="username" className="form-label">UserName</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="userName" value={this.state.userName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label for="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label for="confirmPassword" className="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="confirmPassword" value={this.state.confirmPassword} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("register")]
    public IActionResult Register([FromForm] RegisterRequest request)
    {
        return Content("Controller call successful");
    }
}

public class RegisterRequest
{
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public string? ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `body: JSON.stringify(formData)` to `body: formData`

Comment: @phuzi Nope, still null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set the content-type header.

```
   fetch("api/account/register", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
```

or

```
 fetch("api/account/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            body: formData
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Ooh, good spot. The content-type `application/json` is not compatible with formData payload.

Comment: Thanks. I got method #1 to work, but method #2 didn't work for me - 400 error.